# nginx: TLSv1.3 works with Linux (WSL) but not with Windows

Tags: c#, nginx, ssl

I am trying to connect to my webserver with a C# program.

I allow TLSv1.3:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

and get the error that host and server couldn't agree on an algorithm (on Windows 10):

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
> established, see inner exception.  --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090331): Der Client und der
> Server können keine Daten austauschen, da sie nicht über einen
> gemeinsamen Algorithmus verfügen.AcquireCredentialsHandle(ISSPIInterface secModule,
> String package, CredentialUse intent, SCH_CREDENTIALS* scc)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse
> credUsage, SCH_CREDENTIALS* secureCredential)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandleSchCredentials(X509Certificate
> certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean
> isServer)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SslStreamCertificateContext
> certificateContext, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy,
> Boolean isServer)    at
> System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]&
> thumbPrint)    at
> System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output)    at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1
> incomingBuffer)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean
> isApm)    at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean
> async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)

the strange thing is: it works perfectly fine on Linux (WSL).

My nginx (version `1.21.3`) config:

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/ssl.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
}
```

If I scan my server with `sslscan` I get this output:

```
  SSL/TLS Protocols:
SSLv2     disabled
SSLv3     disabled
TLSv1.0   disabled
TLSv1.1   disabled
TLSv1.2   disabled
TLSv1.3   enabled

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Server supports TLS Fallback SCSV

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLSv1.3 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Preferred TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        Curve 25519 DHE 253
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256  Curve 25519 DHE 253

  Server Key Exchange Group(s):
TLSv1.3  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.3  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.3  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.3  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.3  224 bits  x448

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
RSA Key Strength:    4096
```

In case I allow TLSv1.2 on nginx (and the C# program) everything also works in Windows.

Any idea which cipher-suite I am missing in my nginx-config?

Comment: *Don't* hard-code the TLS level. This only *prevents* the application from using better versions. .NET Core lets the OS negotiate the protocol and use the best available version. You can't make the OS use a TLS version that isn't installed. Which Windows 10 version are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We only want to allow TLSv1.3 for security reasons. My local windows version is `Version 20H2 Build 19042.1415`

Comment: The [Windows Security Blog](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/08/20/taking-transport-layer-security-tls-to-the-next-level-with-tls-1-3/) explains that TLS 1.3 is enabled by default since 2020 with build 20170. Are you using an unsupported version of Windows perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean with unsupported? I use Windows 10 64-bit Pro with a legal license

Comment: Windows 10 is a service offering that's upgraded automatically, which means older versions go out of support in [about 18 months](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro). In any case, [TLS 1.3 was added in Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-11).

Comment: **Why** do you want to disable the TLSv1.2 protocol used by all major services? It's not broken or considered insecure. You own software connects to Amazon, Azure and Google using TLS 1.2.

Comment: I'll have to double on the why, because trying to use a more "secure" but less tested version can lead to some pretty ugly security holes. There have been quite a few incidents with OpenSSL in the last couple of years. How often are your Linux clients updated?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, I am just a developer following our internal rules. I will talk about this with  my colleagues

Comment: We have Version `20H2` so we are fine for a couple more months. I don't understand how the Version can be pretty recent but the build number very old?

Comment: @bopeh74638: *"I don't understand how the Version can be pretty recent but the build number very old?"* - 20H2 is not pretty recent. It was released 05/20, i.e. more than 18 month ago. As already explained, TLS 1.3 support was added later.

Comment: Make sure you are using Net 4.7.2 or later where the default is to use the operating system for TLS instead of Net.  Also if you are using a phone make sure the kernel has been updated.  TLS 1.3 uses different encryption modes which may not be supported in Net or older versions of the operating system.

Comment: TLS 1.3 is not yet available on Windows 10 client versions, see support matrix https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, thank you. That's unfortunate

Comment: The August 2020 build was an Insider Preview build. At some point that Insider preview became Windows 11. If you check the [Windows 10 release versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information) and [Windows 11 release versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information) you'll see that the 2x versions became Windows 11

Comment: There was talk of 21H2 getting it but didn't happen in the end